# Truncate nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(n) with ellipses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What's the quickest way to convert nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(n) and indicate there's more data?

eg: convert the column Address to nvarchar(100) and if Address is larger than 100 characters then replace the last 3 characters with "..."

Comment: So, it would be 97 chars and "..."?

Comment: @Lamak yes, that's correct

Comment: should trailing spaces be included in the character count?

Comment: So you just want to throw that data away?

Comment: @Laurence yes no need to check for that. already removed all leading and trailing spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Address = SUBSTRING(t.Address, 1, 97) + '...'
FROM TableName t
WHERE LEN(t.Address) > 100;

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
  ALTER COLUMN Address NVARCHAR (100);
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work?, you first convert the column to `NVARCHAR(100)` and then check if the column is longer than 100 chars?

Comment: shouldn't ALTER TABLE go after UPDATE?

Comment: @James It should, the `ALTER TABLE` would throw an error otherwise

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Table
 SET [Address] =   CASE 
                       WHEN LEN([Address]) > 100 
                       THEN CAST([Address] AS NVARCHAR(97)) + N'...'
                       ELSE CAST([Address] AS NVARCHAR(100)) 
                   END
```

now change the data type of your column since all the data more than 100 characters will be truncated after the above statement.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN [Address] NVARCHAR(100)
GO
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHEN LEN([Address]) > 100`?